# Programmatically schedule the execution of a component

Tags: 7, rules

I have found the function `rules_scheduler_schedule_task()` under the rules module which supposedly does exactly what I want, but I have trouble interpreting how the function arguments are built. The arguments of that function are an array with the following keys :

- config: The machine readable name of the to be scheduled component.
- date: When the component should be executed.
- identifier: User provided string to identify the task per scheduled

And finally :

- state: A rules evaluation state to use for scheduling.

I don't have any trouble with the first three arguments, but what is the meaning of the later (`state`) ? Is it where I put the arguments of the components ?
Could someone provide an example ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an older post, but I had the same problem, and found this post. I found the answer so maybe someone can use it later:

```
$state = new RulesState();
$state->addVariable('variable_name', $variable, array());
// 3rd parameter is called $info it must be an array, but i don't know it's function

$task = array(
'identifier' => 'unique_id_of_scheduled_task',
'date' => time(), // timestamp
'config' => 'id_of_the_rule_component_to_run',
'state' => $state,
);

rules_scheduler_schedule_task($task);
```

So you have to create a RulesState object and pass in that in place of the 'state' parameter.
I had to do this because in Rules I couldn't get the timestamp I wanted when I was configuring the "Schedule component evaluation" action.

Answer (score 1):

The code for $State can be found in `rules/includes/rules.states.inc`.  It looks like the class holds basic status information for a variety of conditions.  Good hunting!

Comment: I did _that_ hunting, but I need help in understanding the actual construction/content of that class.